# Round date math to nearest month while calculating UNIX time

Tags: linux, bash, unix-timestamp

I want to acquire the UNIX timestamp value (seconds since January 1st 1970) for an offset from the present, while rounding the result to the beginning of the month.

Essentially I want this output -- two months from current date, but the first day of that month.

```
date -d "2019-04-01" "+%s"
1554102000
```

However I don't want to manually add the date. I want to do something similar to this:

```
date -d +"%Y%m" --date="+2 month" +"%s"
1555973219
```

but unfortunately this gives me the incorrect timestamp (the result is not rounded to the beginning of the month).

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What are the two months added to? The current date?

Comment: What's with using both `-d` and `--date` in the latter form?

Comment: Using GNU date, it should just be `date -d 'now + 2 months' +%s`. No reason to overcomplicate things.

Comment: No Charles, your suggestion gives me the timestamp for 2 months from current date. If you look at my example it shows 2 months from now but the very first day of the month.

Comment: Oh, so **that's** what you want. It helps to explain things in English and not expect people to infer intent from code which, after all, is known not to do what you want.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use `date` for this? It'd be trivial with Python builtins.

Comment: I've edited my description to clarify this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demonstrating that this all works correctly when using GNU `date`:

```
set -x
date
start_of_2mo_hence=$(date -d 'now + 2 months' +%Y-%m-01)
start_of_2mo_hence_sec=$(date -d "$start_of_2mo_hence" +%s)
date -d "@$start_of_2mo_hence_sec"
```

...emits:

```
+ date
Fri Feb 22 17:04:49 CST 2019
++ date -d 'now + 2 months' +%Y-%m-01
+ start_of_2mo_hence=2019-04-01
++ date -d 2019-04-01 +%s
+ start_of_2mo_hence_sec=1554094800
+ date -d @1554094800
Mon Apr  1 00:00:00 CDT 2019
```

Of course, this could be simplified to:

```
start_of_2mo_hence_sec=$(date -d "$(date -d 'now + 2 months' +%Y-%m-01)" +%s)
```

Comment: BTW, if you want to enforce UTC rather than local time, consider making it `start_of_2mo_hence_utc_sec=$(TZ=UTC date -d "$(TZ=UTC date -d 'now + 2 months' +%Y-%m-01)" +%s)`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want to do. This should accomplish it and always give you the seconds of the start of the month 2 months from now.

```
date +"%Y-%m" -d "+2 month" | xargs -i date -d "{}-1" "+%s"
1554091200
```

Although it seems to be the case that we're in different time zones. You can either add a time zone or add the UTC flag to the xargs portion of the statement.